# Image not showing up on pygame screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am making my own game with pygame for the first time, and I'm using sprites. I'm trying to blit an image onto the screen but it doesn't work. All it shows is a blank white screen.
Here is the code:

```
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()
    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        return image

class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x =0
    change_y = 0
    def __init__(self):
        image = pygame.Surface([256, 256]).convert()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Bomb_anim0001.png")
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 256, 256)

pygame.init()
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
  
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    bomb  = Bomb()
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

This is the image:
[Click on this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/022wO.png)

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the image on the `screen` *Surface*.

But there is more to be done. Add a `rect` attribute to the `Bomb` class:

```py
class Bomb(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Bomb_anim0001.png")
        self.image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 256, 256)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y) 
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
```

Create a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and add the `bomb` to the *Group*. [`draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) all the sprites in the *Group* on the screen:_

```py
bomb  = Bomb(100, 100)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(bomb)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` mehtod of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Comment: Gives me an error- "self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'Bomb' object has no attribute 'image' ". What should I do?

Comment: Haha, can't believe I missed that! But it looks like errors can't leave me alone XD Now I get this: ```File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 159, in add_internal
    self.__g[group] = 0
AttributeError: 'Bomb' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'```

Comment: I had that in my code, but it was giving me errors so I removed it. Can you please give me a brief explanation of what it does? And thank you so very much for your help, I spent hours trying to fix this.

Comment: @PianoPianist It is used to invoke the constructor of the base class `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. See [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)